# connect ECONNREFUSED - node js , sql

Tags: mysql, node.js

**I have the next code in a js file:**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var TEST_DATABASE = 'nodejs_mysql_test';
var TEST_TABLE = 'test';
var client = mysql.createClient({
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
});

client.query('CREATE DATABASE '+TEST_DATABASE, function(err) {
  if (err && err.number != mysql.ERROR_DB_CREATE_EXISTS) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

**But I get this error:**

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:632:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:623:18)
```

As I understand it, this is a connection problem - but how do I solve it?

( I'm working on windows 7)

Thanks!!

Comment: It would seem that for some reason the page thinks the database is up and running. It is up and running on localhost, right?

Comment: obvious question: is mysql running on the same machine, on port 3306? can you `telnet localhost 3306`?

Comment: when I write in CMD the line    
telnet localhost 3306 
I get:
'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 Is that what you mean?

Comment: @user1087995: what seppo0010 is getting at is are you absolutely sure there is a MySQL server running on the local machine and listening on port 3306, per the connection settings that you are using?  This error indicates that you are trying to connect to a server which is not listening.

Comment: Even if it's running on the local machine, you need to be sure that MySQL is listening on localhost/127.0.0.1 and not just the external IP.

Answer (score 19):

I know two ways to solve it:

1. In `mysql.conf`, comment `skip-networking`.
2. Try to set the socket like this:

   ```
   var client = mysql.createClient({
   user: uuuu,
   password: pppp,
   host: '127.0.0.1',
   port: '3306',
   _socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',});
   ```

Comment: Thanks, commenting skip-networking worked for me, but the key did not, that's weird. On production I'd rather not have that option commented!

Comment: This was a rejected edit by an anonymous user:
I had the same problem, so i just inserted how i solved my problem.
Make sure you have the correct bind-address in the mysql config file (`/etc/mysql/ my.cnf` or `mysql.conf`). Below you have an example of what you should write in this case: `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: I don't know why but only this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20486467/2413469

Comment: In version 2.1.0 you should use ```socketPath``` instead of ```_socket```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when MySQL Server was not running.

I changed my configuration via Initialize Database in MySQL.PrefPane, the System Preferences tool for MySQL on OS X - to Use Legacy Password Encryption - to fix ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE.
This config change stopped MySQL Server and then I got ECONNREFUSED when I tried to connect to MySQL from node.js.

Fixed by restarting MySQL Server from the MySQL System Preferences tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your defined port in mysql and your Node.js script.
You can define the mysqld port in the ***.cnf** file inside the mysql directory,
and you can define that port when you connect to MySQL in your Node.js script.

Something like this in the cnf file

```
port = 3306
```