# How to tell node.js that mysql is not running on default port?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mamp

I'm having a problem similar to this person's: [connect ECONNREFUSED - node js , sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825342/connect-econnrefused-node-js-sql)

I'm trying to connect app.js to an existing database running as part of MAMP. MAMP runs mysql on port 8889; how do I tell node.js which port to find mysql on?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you are initializing the mysql client, along with username and password, you can pass a different value for port.

```js
const client = mysql.createClient({
  user: '??',
  password: '??',
  port: 8889
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those initializing the mysql connection object using `mysql.createPool({...})`, it's the same solution as the accepted answer. [For Reference](https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/mysql/createPool)

```js
   const connection = mysql.createPool({
      host: ...,
      port: 8889,
      user: ...,
      password: ...,
    });
```