# nodejs and mysql connection failing?

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var client = mysql.createClient({
  user: 'myusername',
  password: 'mypassword',
});

client.query('USE mydb');
```

A simple setup like this using node's mysql is returning an ECONNREFUSED error, although the credentials are correct and permissions are updated. I have even used a different node module to successfully connect/query the database using the same credentials, but the syntax of this module is in my opinion far superior.

Anyone have an idea whats causing this to go wrong?

Error:

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825342/connect-econnrefused-node-js-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In mysql.conf, comment skip-networking.
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating the database you need to use the command ***`CreateConnection`*** and not ***`createClient`***, make the necessary changes and that should work !

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var client = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'myusername',
  password: 'mypassword',
});

client.query('USE mydb');
```

**Note** that you have not mentioned which database you are accessing !

- Source for this solution:: Check [***NODEJS Github here***](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)