# ECONNREFUSED error while running express code

Tags: node.js, express

I am not able to run the server ...... I am getting the error as `ECONNREFUSED`

**How to resolve this Error !**

When i tried to use different ports .... all are giving me the same error !

```
ubuntu@ip-MyIP:~/rainmelon/projects/FindMyBuffet$ node app.js
Express server listening on port 7005

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:875:19)
    --------------------
    at Handshake.Sequence (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/projects/FindMyBuffet/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:15:20)
    at new Handshake (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/projects/FindMyBuffet/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:9:12)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/projects/FindMyBuffet/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:42:50)
    at Connection.connect (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/projects/FindMyBuffet/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/projects/FindMyBuffet/app.js:15:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: because some other thing is running on that port

Comment: fuser -k 7005/tcp          .............. i used that command to kill it but dosent seem to work .... any solution

Comment: Still same error persists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The traceback says where the exception is coming from:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:875:19)
    --------------------
    ...
    at Connection.connect (.../node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:73:18)
-->                                         ^^^^^
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/projects/FindMyBuffet/app.js:15:12)
-->                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

So your app can't connect to MySQL.

This is usually down to either incorrect hostname/portname in your MySQL driver configuration, the MySQL server not running, or that your MySQL server isn't configured to listen on TCP sockets. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606656/893780).

Comment: My express server was functioning correctly ....all of a sudden it stopped .... when i checked it it was showing this error ...in server..... this error was caused when i had made no changes to my previous code .... & i did check your solution.... still same error is popping again ... any ideas ?

Comment: @smriti2 what's at line 15 of your `app.js` file?

Comment: @smriti2 perhaps you should edit your answer and post some code, esp where the error occurs. Hard to debug from just an error message.

Comment: I resolved the error ........... With your input(I identified that Mysql had stopped & i didnt knwq abt it)  ..... I restarted the mysql server ..... now its functioning ..... thanks !........... i used sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: @smriti2 glad to hear it's solved, I added the MySQL server being down as another reason why the error might occur :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql process is down, which means it is not running. You need to restart your mysql process (changing ports wont help).
To solve this problem you need to restart it. You can do by doing any of the following:

1. You can start your wamp or xamp server which will automatically start the process.
2. Or you can open the commandline prompt and start it manually like so "c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysqld.exe"

> Note that using the second method will require knowing the exact location of your wamp folder like I have used mine up top.(in quotes)

Comment: Please use proper capitalization/grammar.

Answer (score -1):

You may do a `netstat` to find out the pid of process running on the port `7005` and then go for a `forceful kill` with the pid got.

like

```
 netstat -plten |grep 7005
 kill -9 16085
```

where 16085 is the pid obtained from prev command. And restart the express app.

reference

[How to kill a process running on particular port in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux)

Comment: I tried using the first one of your commands .... i get the error as ... ((Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.))

Comment: i was in root directory when i was using it .... ...one more thing .... all the ports are behaving like this .... is this can be server error ... or should i apply something else ?

Comment: @smriti2 : so may be you should try running your express app as root.

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` is not the error you get when there's already something listening on a port you're trying to bind to, that's `EADDRINUSE`.