# node.js + public mysql database : "connect ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: mysql, node.js, proxy

I'm working behind a proxy and I'm trying to access a following **public** database.

The connection works using a mysql client, from my workplace:

```
$ mysql -A -u genome -h genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu -P 3306 -D hg19 -e 'select now()'
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2014-03-06 01:56:36 |
+---------------------+
```

Now, I'm trying to do the same thing using **node**:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  debug:true,
  trace:true,
  host : 'genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu',
  port : 3306,
  database: 'hg19',
  user : 'genome',
  password: ''
 });
connection.connect(function(err) {if(err!=null) console.log(err);});
connection.end();
```

It works from my home but it raises an error from my workplace

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

same error using :  `_socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'` as [connect ECONNREFUSED - node js , sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825342)

Any suggestion on how to fix this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [connect ECONNREFUSED - node js , sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825342/connect-econnrefused-node-js-sql)

Comment: not a duplicate: it's not my mysql server I cannot set 'skip networking' and I tried the solution you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed. That was a problem with my version of node.js:

fixed. It was a probem with my node on ubuntu

```
lindenb@hardyweinberg:~/tmp/NODE$ /usr/bin/node -v && /usr/bin/node test2.js
v0.6.12
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

vs

```
$ ~/package/node/bin/node -v && ~/package/node/bin/node test2.js
v0.10.26
<-- HandshakeInitializationPacket
{ protocolVersion: 10,
  serverVersion: '5.6.10-log',
  threadId: 9810250,
  scrambleBuff1: <Buffer 46 33 6a 3f 39 41 79 61>,
  filler1: <Buffer 00>,
  serverCapabilities1: 63487,
  serverLanguage: 8,
  serverStatus: 2,
  serverCapabilities2: 32895,
  scrambleLength: 21,
  filler2: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>,
  scrambleBuff2: <Buffer 5a 7c 26 43 5c 28 50 3c 79 6d 39 71>,
  filler3: <Buffer 00>,
  pluginData: 'mysql_native_password',
  protocol41: true }
```

Comment: This appears to be a common issue due to the old Node.js version on the ubuntu repositories.  Perhaps, we can get a comment added on the README for node-mysql, or another centralized location.