# Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ENOENT

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache, nginx

I am stuck at a point. I am trying to start /connect using command "npm start" but unable to start npm on server.

I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ENOENT
    at Handshake._callback (/home/ec2-user/webapps/vactivity/node/vactivity/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:63:20)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/home/ec2-user/webapps/vactivity/node/vactivity/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/home/ec2-user/webapps/vactivity/node/vactivity/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:358:14)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (/home/ec2-user/webapps/vactivity/node/vactivity/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:382:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

Apart from this my website work on nodejs & have nginx server configured on server.

Every thing started when I tried to set apache for adding a wordpress blog website. Since nginx already working on port 80. I was trying to set apache on another port so that everything work and ended up with above error. Now my website is not starting at all.

Edit:
My website is running using nodejs. I needed a wordpress blog website to run along and so i checked if there is a scope for apache on my server.
I found that apache along with nginx service was already running and mysql as well.

- nginx is essential to run "adminer", a database management tool
- Since nginx and apache was running on same ports, i tried to set apache on another port, other than default port.
- After that I restarted apache, stopped mysql, stopped nginx and also stopped node
- I used `pkill node` command for stopping node service.
- Then restarted everything but got the above error.
- I tried many things, and finally reset everything.
- Ever since then I am stuck on this error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your DB running? It looks like Sequelize can't connect to mysql

Comment: I have verified that mysql server is running. What else I am suppose to do?

Comment: What port number do you use for apache?

Comment: Actually Apache is not running yet. It was listening to port 80 by default. Currently, I have the Nginx server on and it too should be running on 80 by default. No matter what I do, the error never ever seems to go away. And I have not found a single resolution about connect ENOENT error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured the problem and solved it.

`Connect ENOENT` means that system is unable to connect to mysql because its path is not correct.

As mentioned in an approved answer from [Connect MySQL with Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866133/cant-connect-to-mysql-with-sequelize)

Update your models/index.js file with the mentioned code. 
To find you mysql socket path go to file here `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` ( this path may depend on your server). For my case it was `/etc/my.cnf`. Here you will find the socket path. Now paste this path to the code above and do `npm start`.

Problem is resolved. :)