# Node App is not working correctly on Google App Engine

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have connected my node app to my Cloud SQL database and it is working perfectly locally, but when I deploy my node app to App Engine, the API no longer works. In the logs I can see the following:

(node:11) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT

This does not happen when I run the app locally despite being connected to the same Google Cloud SQL DB.

I thought maybe it would not connect because of security restrictions, but on the SQL connections page it says the following:

Apps in this project: All authorized.

My node app is deployed within the same project, so that shouldn't be the problem.I have also whitelisted my home IP so that I could connect locally, and that was a success as mentioned before. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is my attempt to connect to the DB. It now fails locally & when I deploy. It works locally if I pass in the public IP to the "host."

```
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('linkspot', 'kyle', 'password', {
        host: '/cloudsql/linkspot:us-central1:linkspot-mysql',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        port: 3306,
        pool: {
         max: 5,
         min: 1,
         acquire: 30000,
         idle: 10000
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

When you connect in your local computer the connection is made via the SQL Proxy, but when the app is deployed in app engine several [steps](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#configuring) are needed to configure app engine depending if its using private or public IP.

For instance private ip connections requires you to create a Serverless VPC Access connector in the same VPC network as your Cloud SQL instance, and public IP connections require you to use unix domain socket using the format: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME.

For the instructions on both cases check this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#configuring)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. After trying what you suggested, I am still struggling. I checked my logs and see this message: (node:10) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND /cloudsql/linkspot:us-central1:linkspot-mysql /cloudsql/linkspot:us-central1:linkspot-mysql:3306

Comment: I edited my question with my code where I try to connect.

Comment: Have you checked that the service account of your GAE has one of the needed SQL roles? Cloud SQL Client (preferred), Cloud SQL Editor, Cloud SQL Admin
I am not familiar with Sequelize, not sure if it is considering that the connection would have to be through a [unix socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866133/cant-connect-to-mysql-with-sequelize)
The GCP NodeJS  [SQL example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/mysql/server.js) do things a little different without sequelize.

Comment: You could try the private IP method with Sequelize (private IP method doesn't use unix sockets)